# Why pip works and conda didn't?

Tags: python, pip, conda

Suppose we create multiple Python environments using Conda:

```
conda create --name py38 python=3.8

conda create --name py39 python=3.9

conda activate py39
```

Sometimes, trying to install a package in one of these environments, like so:

```
conda install somepackage
```

will fail with an error like:

`conda.exceptions.PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels"`

But using Pip to install the same package into the same environment created by Conda may succeed:

```
conda activate py39 
conda install pip
python -m pip install somepackage
```

Why does this happen?